# MongoDB BI --sampleSize option not working correctly

Tags: mongodb

I have a database contain about 10k of document, to correctly generate schema, I need include all document, so I follow the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongosqld/#std-option-mongosqld.--sampleSize) set --sampleSize as zero,

```
mongosqld --schemaRefreshIntervalSecs 10 --sampleSize 0 --sampleNamespaces companyDB.sample --schemaSource schemaDB --schemaMode auto
```

But when I check my [schema source db](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongosqld/#std-option-mongosqld.--schemaSource), looks like it didn't really include all document to generate table
[image: sampleSize 0]

Because when I increase the sampleSize to 5000, it actually generate more table

```
mongosqld --schemaRefreshIntervalSecs 10 --sampleSize 5000 --sampleNamespaces companyDB.sample --schemaSource schemaDB --schemaMode auto
```

[image]

How do I correctly include all documents to generate schema, or there's any other option to generate schema base on specific document which included all field I needed?